# Elastic search query migration from 1.x to 7.x for matching phrases

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-analyzers, match-phrase

I have a requirement to modify elastic search query from 1.x to 7.x. The 1.x query is given below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "header": [
                  "target"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "from": "2010-07-23",
                  "to": "2010-07-23",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "or": {
                "filters": [
                  {
                    "query": {
                      "match": {
                        "message": {
                          "query": "word1 word2 word3",
                          "type": "phrase",
                          "operator": "AND"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns document if it contains `word1 word2 word3` and also if the document has `xxxxword1 word2 word3` or `word1 word2 word3xxxx` or `xxxword1 word2 word3xxx`.

Since the AND, OR operators support is deprecated in later Elasticsearch versions, I'm using should and must keywords and created below query to be complaint with 7.x:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "header": [
              "target"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "from": "2010-07-23",
              "to": "2010-07-23",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "message": {
                    "query": "word1 word2 word3",
                    "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But the new query does not return if the document contain `xxxxword1 word2 word3` or `word1 word2 word3xxxx` or `xxxword1 word2 word3xxx`.

I tried adding `"type": "bool_prefix"` to the new query. but it gives more results than expected. is there any alternative to achieve this requirement?

Also, is there any performance issue in using match_phrase instead of multi_match with single field.